# error C3863: array type 'double [length]' is not assignable

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

In windows MSVC, I was trying to compile the below code.

```
void foo(std::vector<double> &bar){
    const long int length = bar.size();
    double a[length]; //error C3863: array type 'double [length]' is not assignable
    for(int i=0; i < length; i++){
        a[i]=0.0;
    }
    //do some other things
}
```

the code works fine in xcode.

When I switch to MSVC, compile the code with command line:

```
cl /EHsc main.cpp /std:c++17
```

Then I have the "error C3863: array type 'double [length]' is not assignable".

Why is it different? How to get rid of the error?

Comment: `double a[length];` is a [VLA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard) (not included in standard C++). Make `a` a `std::vector<double>` instead: `std::vector<double> a(bar.size());` would do what you are trying to do now, but using standard C++. It has the added benefit that you don't need to set all values to `0.0` afterwards too.

Comment: `double a[length];` is not legal C++, XCode is misleading you. Array bounds must be compile time constants, `length` is a variable. Use a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Some C++ compilers implement VLA as an extension. MSVC is not one of them.

Comment: I suggest that you add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pedantic-errors` when compiling from xcode to not get surprises like this when trying to compile your programs with other compilers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`double a[length];` is not portable C++ as variable length arrays are not implemented by the language.

```
std::vector<double> a(bar.size());
```

is the replacement. Note that the elements will be initialised to zero for you, so you can remove the initialisation loop.